# Development Environmet Suggestions

Tags: javascript, php, linux, windows, development-environment

I want to separate my development environment and daily multimedia and entertainment activities. Question is that should I just install a Linux OS standalone or should I use Linux beside Windows OS. What are the benefits for standalone Linux or the other way? How you guys are using your development environment? Do you just integrate some apps into Windows or do you use both of the OS? BTW I'm building web apps mostly.

Comment: This is what Virtual Boxes were invented for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve by doing this. I assume that currently you are using Windows. First of all, why do you need Linux as development environment? You know that you can run 2 Windowses the same way you would run Windows + Linux.

Second, do you want this because you have some "stuff" running in your Windows which would slow down/interfere with your development work? 
If it is just that it might interfere then virtual machine running your new operating system would be the choice. Otherwise it is good to actually install 2 operating systems.

And as a web developer, I have never needed to do any kind of separation except of some folder naming. It is up to you but it is not really needed.

Comment: Yes I'm currently on Windows. Thanks for your comment I think the second advise will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

usually your development server is exactly the same as your production server.  if you are using Windows and IIS then you create a new server with the same software.